# Determining Parity of Decaying Quantum System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-spin, parity

> Show that a particle of spin $1$ cannot decay into two identical particles of spin $0$. The $\rho$-meson has spin $1$ and can decay into two spinless (spin-$0$) $\pi$-mesons, or pions, with different charges. If the intrinsic parity of any $\pi$ is negative ($\eta_\pi =-1$), then what is the intrinsic parity of the $\rho$?

(I realise that there is a similar question here: [Parity of a decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46616/parity-of-a-decay) - please read on before marking as a duplicate!)

I can do the first bit ok (I think!). What is confusing me is that the initially the total angular momentum $j=1$ (given $l=0$, using the frame of the initial particle). This is conserved. Both new particles are spin-$0$, so their product is in any combination (this is correct yes?). Thus we require $l=1$ for one $\pi$ and $l=0$ for the other $\pi$ (and hence not identical, and so not violating the first part of the question). Surely this means that that total parity of the new system is
$$(-1)^{0+1}\eta_\pi^2 = -1.$$
(I assume that the fact that $\eta_\pi = -1$ as opposed to $+1$ doesn't matter since they multiply together to get $+1$ either way - the point is that all have the same intrinsic parity. Correct?) Since we're assuming that $l=0$ initially, must we have negative intrinsic parity, ie $\eta_\rho = -1$, so that
$$(-1)^0 \eta_\rho = -1$$
(and so conserved). But the opposite result is given in the question liked above, [Parity of a decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46616/parity-of-a-decay).

Just as I was typing this up, I realise that the answer to my confusion may be the following: the initial spin is $1$, so the internal parity has a $(-1)^1$ multiplied - this then gives $\eta_\rho = +1$. I'm not convinced that this is right though.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Currently, I'm reckoning that the linked question's answer is wrong: we should have $\eta_\rho = -1$. Through further investigation, I have found that this is the case...

Comment: Hi Smiley Sam - our etiquette here on Stack Exchange is that you don't end your posts with things like "Thank you" or "Any help would be appreciated". For many people who post here, such things are just an unnecessary distraction from the main content of the post.

Comment: Some people like it some don't - most don't to be fair, but I'm one of the few that likes it. While I don't post much on physics SE, I do quite a lot on maths SE, so I'm not a newbie - it's just how I prefer! :)